# xkb config has pointless entry?

Tags: x11, xkb

I dumped the current xkb configuration with `xkbcomp :0 keyboard.xkb` and found that, for example, ISO_Level3_Shift has two 'interpret' entries:

```
interpret ISO_Level3_Shift+AnyOf(all) {
    virtualModifier= LevelThree;
    useModMapMods=level1;
    action= SetMods(modifiers=LevelThree,clearLocks);
};
# ⋮
interpret ISO_Level3_Shift+AnyOfOrNone(all) {
    action= SetMods(modifiers=LevelThree,clearLocks);
};
```

But it seems to me that the first entry has no effect at all. So, why is it included at all?